# How can i get unique suggestions without duplicates when i use completion suggester?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, search-suggestion

I am using elastic 5.1.1 in my environment. I have chosen completion suggester on a field name `post_hashtags` with an array of strings to have suggestion on it. I am getting response as below for prefix "inv"

Req:

```
POST hashtag/_search?pretty&&filter_path=suggest.hash-suggest.options.text,suggest.hash-suggest.options._source
{"_source":["post_hashtags" ],

"suggest": {
    "hash-suggest" : {
        "prefix" : "inv",
        "completion" : {
            "field" : "post_hashtags"
        }
    }
}
```

Response :

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "hash-suggest": [
      {
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "invalid",
            "_source": {
              "post_hashtags": [
                "invalid"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "text": "invalid",
            "_source": {
              "post_hashtags": [
                "invalid",
                "coment_me",
                "daya"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here "invalid" is returned twice because it is also a input string for same field "post_hashtags" in other document.

Problems is if same "invalid" input string present in 1000 documents in same index then i would get 1000 duplicated suggestions which is huge and not needed.

Can I apply an aggregation on a field of type completion ?

Is there any way I can get unique suggestion instead of duplicated text field, even though if i have same input string given to a particular field in multiple documents of same index ?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41800102/4604579

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ElasticSearch 6.1 has introduced the [skip_duplicates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/search-suggesters-completion.html) operator. Example usage:

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "prefix": "MySearchTerm",
      "completion": {
        "field": "name",
        "skip_duplicates": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: This answer only applies to Elasticsearch 5*

No, you cannot de-duplicate suggestion results. The autocomplete suggester is document-oriented in Elasticsearch 5 and will thus return suggestions for all documents that match.

In Elasticsearch 1 and 2, the autocomplete suggester automatically de-duplicated suggestions. There is an open Github ticket to [bring back this functionality](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22912), and it looks like it is [possible to do so](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23364) in a future version.

For now, you have two options:

1. Use Elasticsearch version 1 or 2.
2. Use a different suggestion implementation not based on the autocomplete suggester. The only semi-official suggestion I have seen so far involve putting your suggestion strings in a [separate index](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22912#issuecomment-277189389).