# elasticsearch - search as you type - return each suggested word only once

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index where the contents of many text documents is saved. The field-type for the fulltext-field is the new "search_as_you_type"-datatype.

I want to implement a auto-completion feature like google does.
When I use prefix-query I get a lot of hits containing the same word. But I want to get each completion-suggestion-word only once.
Maybe I was not able to google the right way, but I did not find an answer myself, that's the reason I ask here.

So If I enter "th" in the search-field, auto-completion should list the words "the", and "that" only once, even if these words are contained in hundreds of indexed documents. Any help on this topic would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help.

> The completion suggester provides auto-complete/search-as-you-type functionality. This is a navigational feature to guide users to relevant results as they are typing, improving search precision. It is not meant for spell correction or did-you-mean functionality like the term or phrase suggesters.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester

Comment: I just learned, that I did not express myself correctly. I would need a feature to auto-complete single words only.
If if index a text with thousands of words(e.g. an article of even a book), and type in the auto-completion-text-field the letters "th" the words that start with "th" should be listed once. Even if this words occur in many documents at many different positions.

Comment: Found this buddy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391207/how-can-i-get-unique-suggestions-without-duplicates-when-i-use-completion-sugges