# Elasticsearch 5 AutoComplete Implementation in Java API

Tags: java, autocomplete, elasticsearch-5

I Have a collection of documents as following format in json

```
{"Title":"String","Author":"String","Link":"String","Description":"String","tags":["x","x","x","x","x"]}
```

I want to store them in an ElasticSearch server and prepare autocomplete suggestion by user entering character based on tags property

Comment: What is your approach towards your goal? Have you run into any specific problems? Can you share code and/or error messages?

Comment: Actually I can not find any resource applicable to elasticsearch  v5 example for implementation autocomplete feature

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744712/word-oriented-completion-suggester-elasticsearch-5-x