# Get the response before finishing typing the query?

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, elasticsearch-query

I am new to elasticsearch, I use it to store my dataset.

I created a IHM where I can type a query and get the response
I would like to know if there is a way to get the response before finishing typing the query

for example, I would like to look for the `china`, I would like to get some result while I am typing the word `chi`.

Comment: This answer would probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41800102/4604579 (hint: use the suggester feature and/or search-as-you-type field type)

Comment: yeah it works, thank you :)